# MariaDB - Geocode query very slow

Tags: mysql, google-maps

I am using MariaDB 10.1.16 and I have a table consisting of 1.7 million UK postcodes which will be used for location auto-complete, geocoding and reverse geocoding.

Below is the table structure:

```
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| postcode    | varchar(8)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| district    | varchar(4)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| postal_town | varchar(35)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| county      | varchar(37)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| country     | varchar(16)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| easting     | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| northing    | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| latitude    | decimal(7,5) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| longitude   | decimal(7,5) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| type        | varchar(14)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| id          | varchar(32)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Querying the table for a single postcode returns a result instantly:

```
MariaDB [dev]> SELECT * FROM uk_postcodes WHERE postcode = "CH5 3NS";
+----------+----------+-------------+--------+---------+---------+----------+----------+-----------+------------+----------------------------------+
| postcode | district | postal_town | county | country | easting | northing | latitude | longitude | type       | id                               |
+----------+----------+-------------+--------+---------+---------+----------+----------+-----------+------------+----------------------------------+
| CH5 3NS  | CH5      | Hawarden    | Clwyd  | Wales   |  331718 |   365725 | 53.18422 |  -3.02325 | Geographic | f99a64139bfb8cf8091ca870808b355b |
+----------+----------+-------------+--------+---------+---------+----------+----------+-----------+------------+----------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

However I now want to use my current location to find the nearest postcode.

My approximate location is: `53.1852582, -3.0198408999999997`

My query:

```
MariaDB [dev]> SELECT postcode, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians( 53.1852582 ) ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(-3.0198408999999997) ) + sin( radians(53.1852582) ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance
    -> FROM uk_postcodes
    -> ORDER BY distance ASC
    -> LIMIT 1;
+----------+---------------------+
| postcode | distance            |
+----------+---------------------+
| CH5 3PF  | 0.13510896180231324 |
+----------+---------------------+
1 row in set (3.10 sec)
```

Although the result is correct, it's taking far too long. But why?

Comment: since you use ORDER BY, you have to perform your calculation for all the entries and sort that resulting set before returning the data. This takes quite a while... if you do an EXPLAIN on your query you might see why...

Comment: You will want to use some kind of spatial index on the data, otherwise you will not get any reasonable performance out of the database.

Comment: do you really need to take a look at ALL the entries, or would it be sufficient to reduce the data to a predefined radius?

Comment: @Olli For now yes, I could restrict it to a specific district, which reduces the total possibilities from 1.7M to 23K. But essentially that's not solving the problem and so I still really need to understand why it's taking so long.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Whats the fastest way to lookup big tables for points within radius MySQL (latitude longitude)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38548473/whats-the-fastest-way-to-lookup-big-tables-for-points-within-radius-mysql-latit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to solve the performance problem!

### TABLE STRUCTURE

```
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| postcode    | varchar(8)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| district    | varchar(4)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| postal_town | varchar(35)  | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| county      | varchar(37)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| country     | varchar(16)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| easting     | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| northing    | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| latitude    | decimal(7,5) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| longitude   | decimal(7,5) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| type        | varchar(14)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| id          | varchar(32)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| latlng      | geometry     | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

---

### SPATIAL INDEX

The latlng field has the spatial index and has been populated as follows:

```
UPDATE uk_postcodes SET latlng = GeomFromText(CONCAT('POINT(',latitude,' ', longitude, ')'));
```

---

### SQL QUERY

```
SELECT postcode, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians( 53.18526 ) ) * cos( radians( X(latlng) ) ) * cos( radians( Y(latlng) ) - radians(-3.01984) ) + sin( radians(53.18526) ) * sin( radians( X(latlng) ) ) ) ) AS distance
FROM uk_postcodes
WHERE MBRContains
(LineString
  (
    Point (53.18526 + 10 / (111.1 / COS(RADIANS(53.18526))), -3.01984 + 10 / 111.1),
    Point (53.18526 - 10 / (111.1 / COS(RADIANS(53.18526))), -3.01984 - 10 / 111.1)
  ),
  latlng
)
ORDER BY distance
LIMIT 1;
```

---

### RESULT

```
+----------+---------------------+
| postcode | distance            |
+----------+---------------------+
| CH5 3PF  | 0.13513453795504218 |
+----------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer is less about the reason WHY its so slow (its calculation of values for every line in your database before ordering) but maybe a quick hack to reduce the number of lines to check:

you can limit the range of data you have to calculate distances for when you limit the latitude/longitude values to the ones nearby. (formulas coming from [these slides](http://de.scribd.com/doc/2569355/Geo-Distance-Search-with-MySQL) (page 12ff) This works when you calculate by miles... otherwise you have to adjust the "69" with the right value for kilometers.

```
1° of latitude ~= 69 miles 
1° of longitude ~= cos(latitude)*69
```

and then you modify your query like so:

```
SELECT 
  postcode, 
  ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians( 53.1852582 ) ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(-3.0198408999999997) ) + sin( radians(53.1852582) ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance
FROM 
  uk_postcodes
WHERE 
  longitude BETWEEN <longitude1> AND <longitude2> 
AND 
  latitude BETWEEN <latitude1> AND <latitude2>
ORDER BY 
  distance ASC
LIMIT 1;
```

with the calculated longitudes/latitudes like mentioned before.

This should improve the overall speed without having to change the database structure.