# Best practice to find locations by city

Tags: mysql, google-maps, geometry

I'm looking for best solution to search locations by some city. Also I need to find locations that could be near, because sometimes we couldn't find locations in a small city, but 5 kilometers away could be a bigger city with some locations. But it's always different value, so I can't imagine how I can know this maximal distance of the search.

**I have three tables:**

`countries`:

`id|code|name`

`cities`:

`id|lat|lng|southwestLat|southwestLng|northeastLat|northeastLng|countryId|name`

`locations`:

`id|lat|lng|cityId|name`

**And I have three ideas:**

1. `select * from locations where cityId = :myCityId`, not a flexible solution, because of this '5 kilometers'
2. search by an intersection with an ellipse or a rectangle with `cities.lat` and `cities.lng` as center, `southwestLat - northeastLat` and `southwestLng - northeastLng` as diameters or with and height, but it's not a flexible solution too, because we can have some city that will be near, but will be not in this range, otherwise this range could include unnecessary cities
3. Get a city polygon (by google maps api etc.) and search just in the city, but it the same like variant 1 and less productive.

Also I can add some distance to increase a size of the polygon/ellipse/rectangle. But which distance?

What do you think about this?
Did you have the same case?
What did you do to resolve it?

Thank you in advance!

**Update 1:** it's not related to [Whats the fastest way to lookup big tables for points within radius MySQL (latitude longitude)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38548473/whats-the-fastest-way-to-lookup-big-tables-for-points-within-radius-mysql-latit) , because this question about the fast search by radius, but I'm looking for solution for best flexible search by the city, instead of some radius.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Whats the fastest way to lookup big tables for points within radius MySQL (latitude longitude)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38548473/whats-the-fastest-way-to-lookup-big-tables-for-points-within-radius-mysql-latit)

Comment: @e4c5 it's just a search in the radius, my problem is more complex and it's not force me to choose exactly this solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find an answer that really satisfies all questions.

Answer (score 0):

There are are couple of ways I have done this, and it depends on the requirements...

**Neighbours Table**

This is usually the fastest as you can index it. If you can obtain the data for all locations to give you the neighbouring locations, you can simply amend the query 1) as:

```
select *
from neighbours n 
inner join locations l on l.cityId = n.neighbourId
where n.cityId = @cityId;
```

The downside of this is you need the leg work of defining all neighbours.

**Great Circle Distance**

If you want to allow locations with exact distance, then you want to look at the [great circle distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance) formula. This will take a while to calculate though, so you can do either one of two options:

1) use the latitude/longitude difference to find nearby locations, then calculate absolute distance. Note this will be skewed once you start moveing too far to the north or south as longitude will change signinificantly for short distances.
2) use a mapping table to calculate the distace between all locations. This will not work if you have user defined locations you need to find the distance from.

**Hybrid Solution**

A Hybrid of the above two can work by calculating the distances between cities (or more arbitrary areas). Assign all locations to one of these areas and then only calculate the distance to locations that are within a certain distance of the search area you have started from.

Comment: It's very interesting to do it by the last way. But where I can find this information about neighbours, because it's too much information to fill them manually.