# Distance calculated by ST_Distance_Sphereh in Meters is invalid

Tags: php, mysql, geo

I've using POINT data type (mysql 5.7) , I want to search points given radious.

This is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE `points` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(45) ,
  `location` point,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
)
```

I've used following sql.

```
SELECT id,X(location),Y(location),
ST_Distance_Sphere(point(30.714006, 76.853478),location)/1000 AS distance 
FROM points HAVING distance < 100;
```

But the distance return by this statement is very less then actual

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21168380/use-mysql-spatial-extensions-to-select-points-inside-circle

Comment: No, I've using POINT datatype so I haven't found any relevant answer.

Comment: So doesn't the answer by `Andrew - OpenGeoCode` in that possible duplicate that I linked use POINT datatype?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Whats the fastest way to lookup big tables for points within radius MySQL (latitude longitude)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38548473/whats-the-fastest-way-to-lookup-big-tables-for-points-within-radius-mysql-latit)