# Limiting mysql results by using function in query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a function that calculates the distance between two points on a map looking like this:

```
function distance($lat1, $lon1, $lat2, $lon2, $unit) {
  $theta = $lon1 - $lon2;
  $dist = sin(deg2rad($lat1)) * sin(deg2rad($lat2)) +         cos(deg2rad($lat1)) * cos(deg2rad($lat2)) * cos(deg2rad($theta));
  $dist = acos($dist);
  $dist = rad2deg($dist);
  $miles = $dist * 60 * 1.1515;
  $unit = strtoupper($unit);

  if ($unit == "K") {
     return ($miles * 1.609344);

   } else if ($unit == "N") {
       return ($miles * 0.8684);
     } else {
        return $miles;
      }
 }
```

And I want to use it so that only rows in a mysql table where the distance is less than a certain value will be returned.

Yes, I could just retrieve all rows and iterate over them, but this is obviously very inefficient. Is there a way to use the function inside a mysql query to limit the results, or any other way to do this without retrieving all rows?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: With `WHERE`-clause?

Comment: Yeah, but it will need to first retrieve the lat- and longitudes from the table before sending them to the function, hence querying on all rows.

Comment: you can't use a jquery function inside mysql .. but you could rewrite  your function in sql for adding a proper where clause to your query..

Comment: A `WHERE` clause alone won't cut it. Not unless he wants to convert the function into a MySQL one. Assuming the lat/long values are fields in the row, you'd have to retrieve rows to use them in a PHP function.

Comment: Right, so there´s actually a way to do the same math in mysql?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Whats the fastest way to lookup big tables for points within radius MySQL (latitude longitude)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38548473/whats-the-fastest-way-to-lookup-big-tables-for-points-within-radius-mysql-latit)

Comment: Pretty sure MySQL has `sin`, `cos`, and `acos` built in, so yeah. All that's left is the deg<->radian conversion, and that's just multiplying/dividing by pi/180 if it's not already built in. (Though it seems it is -- check out the `degrees` and `radians` functions.)

Comment: Thanks guys, never knew mysql can do these sort of more complicated things - that´s the way to go indeed!!!